# Embed Facebook Video in iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, video, uiwebview

is it possible to embed a Facebook Video in a iOS application?

I have searched all over the internet without getting any answer to this question.

please could anyone help with the above problem

Thank you

Comment: any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to embed a Facebook Video in a iOS application?

- YES, I suppose.

Please refer to Facebook's Graph-API documentation here:
And choose iOS SDK:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video

Comment: need login even if video is public

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in ios, not matter you use objective c or swift.
Link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player

Comment: its html player, not native option at all